# How can I query a SQL 2005 XML field with NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

My Microsoft SQL Server 2005 database contains a table that has an XML field that has some important metadata, and under normal SQL I could run the following query and get a list of items which don't have UPC codes set... Unfortunately I'm having a hard time re-creating this query using NHibernate's Criteria API:

```
SELECT [Id],[meta].value( '(/meta/upc)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as upc
FROM 
 [mediaContent].[dbo].[audioVideo]
WHERE
 [meta].value( '(/meta/upc)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') != ''
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although xml fields can be [mapped](http://joeydotnet.com/blog/archive/2009/01/14/nhibernate--xml-columns.aspx) [quite](http://www.hibernate.org/368.html) [seamlessly](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/05/30/NHibernateAndXMLColumnTypes.aspx), I don't think they can be queried like that with HQL or Criteria.

I would stick to SQL in this case.